# Conditional regex problem

Tags: regex

I've a regular expression problem, and I guess I'm missing a point in how the regex actually work.

I've some set of strings that contains methods definitions

- myMethod1()
- myMethod2(argument1 arg1)
- myMethod3(argument1 arg1, argument2 arg2)

but some of them also contains the output type:

- myOtherMethod1() : type1
- myOtherMethod2(argument1 arg1) : type2
- myOtherMethod3(argument1 arg1, argument2 arg2) : whatever

I want to only have inputs like the first ones: take out the output paramaters.
I've taken out my regex hat, and I come up with some conditional regex:

```
(?([:]+)(.+(?=\s:))|(.+))
```

If I match a ":" character in my string, I take whatever is before the " :", if not I take all.
Theoretically this is correct, but it returns the whole line
If I change the regex to

```
(?([:]*)(.+(?=\s:))|(.+))
```

Then the second type of methods are correctly regexed, but not the first ones (strange..).
Can you explain me where is my mistake?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to handle it like this.  Just take up to the first right parentheses you encounter:

```
/^[^)]*\)/
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding your problem...

Comment: Actually your solution works great, my approach of solving the problem was not the good one. Thanks!
Still I don't understand why my regex doesnt work, in theory it should right?

Comment: No.  I think you may want `.*` before the conditional statement (i.e. `(?(.*[:]*)...`).

Comment: surely you don't need `[:]`, as this is just the same as `:`

Comment: ´(?(.*:+)(.+(?=\s:))|(.+))´ (modified version applying both comments didnt work out either. It did 2 matches:
for eg "myOtherMethod1() : type1" gave two matches: "myOtherMethod1()" and " type1"

Comment: @Srodriguez, Precisely as it should.  Remove the last group (`|(.+)`) to not match the ` type1` part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is with your regex. I'd use a simpler regex and just match against want you want:

```
^.*\)
```

This matches a start of line, followed by any character, followed by a `)`. The fact the there may be text after the `)` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with `^(.*?\)).*$`

This matches the start of the string (`^`), followed by any characters up to (and including) the first close parenthesis (`.*?` is lazy match any character, so it will match up to the first `)` (the `\)` is required to escape the string). The rest of the line is ignored (`.*$`) - make you use the multi-line option, else you'll only match the first part.
The extra parenthesis are the capturing group, so you can use $1 as the replacement.